# Restoring form to its previous state in bada

Tags: forms, bada

I need to save a form's current state and restore it while i am navigating between them. I am using FormManager class to navigate between form's. Is it possible to do that with memory handled efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

bada Allows create up to 30 forms per application. You can use `Frame::SetCurrentForm` to make desired form active. But as i see you want have exactly one physically existing form at the time. Imho  common mechanism to saving some state is not exists ( by the way what exactly states you trying to achieve to save? ).

You can try using some own (depends of what exactly you need) user-define format such as some template-based collection from  `Osp::Base::Collection`